# ObstacleLayer and VoxelLayer don't generate obstacles

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic, 2dcostmap, avoid-obstacle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.

I have the issue as i said in the title that ObstacleLayer and VoxelLayer don't generate obstacle. I am using a Realsense camera, model D435 to generate a pointcloud and then using the depthimage_to_laserscan package transform the depth image topic to laser scan topic. It seems to work.

Then I have configured the costmap package as you can see below:

local_costmap_params.yaml

```
local_costmap:
  plugins:
    - {name: laser_layer, type: "costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"} #Laser sensors
    - {name: pointcloud_layer, type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"} #Laser sensors
    - {name: static_map,       type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    - {name: inflation_layer,  type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
    #- {name: ultrasonic,       type: "range_sensor_layer::RangeSensorLayer"}

  update_frequency: 2.0 #HIGH CPU usage with sensors
  publish_frequency: 50.0

  global_frame: "odom" #To inflate obstacles
  robot_base_frame: "base_link"

  #static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 6.0 #6
  height: 6.0 #6
  resolution: 0.05 #0.01
```

global_costmap_params.yaml

```
global_costmap:

  plugins:
    - {name: static_map,       type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
    #- {name: ultrasonic,   type: "range_sensor_layer::RangeSensorLayer"}


  global_frame: "map"
  robot_base_frame: "base_link"

  publish_frequency: 50.0
  update_frequency: 2.0

  resolution: 0.5 #0.01 #The resolution of the map in meters/cell.
  transform_tolerance: 0.2 #Specifies the delay in transform (tf) data that is tolerable in seconds
  map_type: costmap
```

costmap_common_params.yaml

```
footprint: [[-0.30 , 0.38], [0.70, 0.38], [0.70, -0.38], [-0.30, -0.38]]

laser_layer: #Laser
  enabled: true
  obstacle_range: 2.0
  raytrace_range: 4.0
  max_obstacle_height: 2.0
  inflation_radius: 0.7
  combination_method: 1
  observation_sources:  scan
  scan: {data_type: LaserScan, topic: /scan, marking: true, clearing: true, expected_update_rate: 0, sensor_frame: camera_depth_frame}

pointcloud_layer: #Nube de puntos
  enabled: true
  obstacle_range: 2.0
  raytrace_range: 4.0
  inflation_radius: 0.7
  observation_sources: pointcloud
  pointcloud: {data_type: PointCloud2, topic: /camera/depth/color/points, marking: true, clearing: true, expected_update_rate: 0}


inflation_layer:
  enabled: true
  inflation_radius: 0.75
```

base_local_planner_params.yaml

```
#recovery_behavior_enabled: false
#clearing_rotation_allowed: false
controller_frequency: 10 #Default 20 took many time

TrajectoryPlannerROS:

  max_vel_x: 0.4 #meters/sec #0.6
  min_vel_x: -0.1
  max_vel_y: 0.0  # zero for a differential drive robot
  min_vel_y: 0.0  #radians/sec
  max_vel_theta: 1.0 #3
  min_vel_theta: -1.0
  min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.1 #radians/sec, in-place rotations
  escape_vel: -0.1 #0.1
  acc_lim_x: 0.4 #meters/sec^2
  acc_lim_y: 0.0  # zero for a differential drive robot
  acc_lim_theta: 1.0 #radians/sec^2

  holonomic_robot: false

   #####Trajectory Scoring Parameters#####

  meter_scoring: true #goal_distance and path_distance are expressed in units of meters or cells. Cells false.
  #pdist_scale: 0.4 #The weighting for how much the controller should stay close to the path it was given
  #gdist_scale: 0.8 #The weighting for how much the controller should attempt to reach its local goal, also controls speed

  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.5 # about 30 degrees, The tolerance in radians for the controller in yaw/rotation when achieving its goal
  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.20  # 5 cm, The tolerance in meters for the controller in the x & y distance when achieving a goal
   #latch_xy_goal_tolerance: false


   #heading_lookahead: 0.325 #How far to look ahead in meters when scoring different in-place-rotation trajectories
   #heading_scoring: false #Whether to score based on the robot's heading to the path or its distance from the path
   #heading_scoring_timestep: 0.8 #How far to look ahead in time in seconds along the simulated trajectory when using heading scoring
  occdist_scale: 0.07 #The weighting for how much the controller should attempt to avoid obstacles

   #dwa: false

   #####Oscillation Prevention Parameters######
   #oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05 #How far the robot must travel in meters before oscillation flags are reset

   ####Others#######
   #publish_cost_grid_pc: false
   #prune_plan: true
   #simple_attractor: false

  ####Forward Simulation Parameters####

  sim_time: 3.0 #The amount of time to forward-simulate trajectories in seconds
  sim_granularity: 0.05 #The step size, in meters, to take between points on a given trajectory
  #angular_sim_granularity: 0.15 #The step size, in radians, to take between angular samples on a given trajectory
  vx_samples: 10 #The number of samples to use when exploring the x velocity space
  vy_samples: 0  # zero for a differential drive robot
  vtheta_samples: 20.0
```

I am not able to generate obstacle as you can see in the following image of Rviz. (I have to upload the image through drive, because I do not have enough points)

[Rviz Capture](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tO_DU4GKktVB1_G8eK8yTkAryWSNIPgY)

What you see in red is the topic /move_base/local_costmap/pointcloud_layer/clearing_endpoints.
What you see in green is the topic /scan.

If I try to navigate, it does not avoid the obstacle even If it is seen in the pointcloud.

Anyone of them generate obstacle or inflation and I do not know why. If you know any reason or you see any error in the config files please tell me.

Thank you in advance

Best regrets.
Alessandro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346336/obstaclelayer-and-voxellayer-don%27t-generate-obstacles/) by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2020-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please your static layer first. The order matters.

Also, publishing your costmap at 50hz is really unnecessary and will cost you a ton of CPU. Reduce that to *at most* update rate. Its really there to throttle publishing to less than update rate to save cycles.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on 2020-03-10**:
Thank you so much. It worked.

About update_frequency and publish_frequency, what is the difference? Because in the costmap manual I do not understand it very well. (Sorry about this questions, but I am a bit noob on this of ROS)

Best regrets.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-03-10**:
update is how often the costmap thread runs a costmap update cycle (processing all the sensors into a costmap and updating the master costmap). This is costly.

Publish is just how often to publish the costmap to its topic.

**Comment by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on 2020-03-10**:
Okay, thank you again, now I understand it.